# Vim syntax line matching mechanism

Tags: syntax-highlighting, performance, syntax

Can someone explain or link to valid explanation information on the syntax highlighting mechanism. In particular I am having having a hard time understanding how rules are applied.

Imagine the following rule

```
syn match paragraph "^\s*[^\n]*\%(\n[^\n]\+\)\n\n\+"
```

If the applied to a (UNIX) file with of 100 lines. I would expect the pattern to be applied at most 100 times. In reality it is applied much more times.

I have a Markdown syntax file that correctly detects and supports all Pandoc features (and a couple more). But I am confronted with rules being executed tens of thousands times.

Any ideas ?

Comment: How did you measure it was applied that many times? Anyway, I would suggest not to use multiline regexes in  a `syntax match`.

Comment: Using `syntime` to verify (cf. `he syntime`). Multi-line regexes are not the issue here, though I did do some testing to see how they impacted the search -- I also tried changing the regex engine (`\%#`). My concern is how a regex is called, and why it is called so many times.

Answer (score 0):

Found a way round my problem... though I still don't fully understand the underlying logic. So all comments welcome.

By adding a rule that simply matches the start of line and making my previously top-level rules (block level as opposed to inlined in block) contained, I dramatically reduced the number of occurrences, and hence the `syntime`.

```
syn match mdStartOfLine /^/ contains=@mdBlock
```

My `mdStartOfLine` rule is effectively only matched once per line, as opposed to the `paragraph` rule in my original post which was tried thousands of times (the number of trials not apparently linked to the number of lines in the file to hilight).

A (supposedly) side effect of this approach being that I can now use `region` rather than `match`, and consequently don't need to check for the block separator (`\n\n\+`). This significantly simplifies my syntax file.

A lesson learnt for me in this exercise is that a syntax highlighting grammar is not a parser; it doesn't need to *understand*, simply to *detect*.